# Create managed VC++ class with List of another managed VC++ class

Tags: list, class, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am new to VC++, but have been using C# for years. 
I am trying to convert an old C# to VC++ and having hard to understand managed vs unmanaged classes.

This is where I am creating two new classes in AAA.h:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace System;

public ref class BBB
{
public:
   Decimal zzz;
   Decimal yyy;
   DateTime mmddyyyy;
   int vvv;
};

public ref class AAA
{
public:
    AAA(String^ name);
    List<BBB^>^ bbbb;
}
```

In AAA.cpp I have:

```
#include "AAA.h"
using namespace System::IO;
AAA::AAA(String^ name)
{
bbbb = new List<BBB^>;

//do other things
}
```

I wasn't able to figure out how to work out the list in this context.
I am getting C4430 : missing type specifier error.

I would appreciate any help and pointers about this issue.
Thanks

Comment: You are not programming in C++.  This language is called C++/CLI.  You must declare reference types with the ^ hat.  And class declarations need a semi-colon, like `ref class AAA { .. };`  And you don't use a destructor for a class like that.  This is well covered in any tutorial or book about C++/CLI, you need to read one to have a fighting chance to get somewhere.

Comment: Updating code with corrections. Hope this will give me some fighting chance

Comment: List<T> belongs System::Collections::Generic namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** this answer is based on the *original* version of the question, missing `^` in the code and having the classes out of order.

Here is some code to get you going (move the definition of `BBB` before `AAA`):

```
public ref class BBB
{
public:
  Decimal zzz;
  Decimal yyy;
  DateTime mmddyyyy;
  int vvv;
};

public ref class AAA
{
public:
  AAA();
  ~AAA();
  String^ name;
  List<BBB^>^ bbbb;
};
```

As you can see, we *also* need to add `^` to some of these, like `String^` and `List<BBB^>^`. These are "references", and must be used for reference types (you should have been getting errors about that too, as well as your missing `;` at the end of your classes.

In the constructor for `AAA` (or wherever appropriate), you will need to do:

```
bbbb = gcnew List<BBB^>; ///Allocate a new list
```

FYI: `ref class` *is* managed code.

Comment: I figured out. The issue was irrelevant to the code. I put 'AAA.h' in the 'stdafx.h'. Thanks for the help. I am sure I will come back with more question on vc++.